# Modules dependency in Prism are not working

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

i have two modules : one which register some services and on which use them.
However, the second module load first and then throws exception about being unable to resolve the service.

To test, i moved the service registration in App.xaml.cs and using breakpoints i found that the first module was loading after the second. 
I can use this works as a work around but i find it dirty.

After some search i tried to fix it by using module dependency in catalogue configuration and module declaration :

Catalog configuration :

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog) {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);
            moduleCatalog.AddModule<Infrastructure.InfrastructureModule>(ModuleNames.InfrastructureName, InitializationMode.WhenAvailable)
            .AddModule<MainStepper.MainStepperModule>(ModuleNames.MainStepper, InitializationMode.WhenAvailable, ModuleNames.InfrastructureName);
        }
```

Module declaration :

```
    [Module(ModuleName = "Infrastructure")]
    public class InfrastructureModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPrinterService, PrinterService>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IUSBStickService, USBStickService>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IEqpCardRepo, EqpCardRepo>();
        }
    }
```

```
    [Module(ModuleName = "MainStepper")]
    [ModuleDependency("Infrastructure")]
    public class MainStepperModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }
    }
```

However even after those changes, the second module is still loading after the first one.

Why is that not working ?

I'm using DryIoc and .Net 4.6.1

*Edit*

I Tried @Noisy88 solutions but it didn't work either :

```
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog) {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);

        Type MainStepperModuleType = typeof(MainStepper.MainStepperModule);
        Type InfrastructureModuleType = typeof(Infrastructure.InfrastructureModule);

        moduleCatalog.AddModule<Infrastructure.InfrastructureModule>();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo {
            ModuleName = ModuleNames.MainStepper,
            ModuleType = MainStepperModuleType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
            DependsOn = { InfrastructureModuleType.Name }
        });
    }
```

I'm wondering if it is because the first view loaded in the main content region is in `MainStepperModule`.

Comment: More comment than answer, but regarding `the second module load first and then throws exception about being unable to resolve the service` - normally, `RegisterTypes` should do exactly that, _registering_ types, not _resolving_ them, thus totally evading that kind of error.

Comment: The problem is that i register them (using registerSingleton) and in another module i try to use them with Dependency Injection. However, the container cannot resolve them as the registration code has not yet been executed

Answer (score 0):

You should set DependsOn property in a ModuleInfo class instance before adding module. DependsOn requires a collection of module names.

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
{
   base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);


   var moduleA = typeof(ModuleAModule);
   var moduleB = typeof(ModuleBModule);
   var moduleC = typeof(ModuleCModule);
   var moduleInfoB = new ModuleInfo
   {
       DependsOn = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string> { moduleA.Name, moduleC.Name },
       ModuleName = moduleB.Name,
       ModuleType = moduleB.AssemblyQualifiedName

    };

    moduleCatalog.AddModule(moduleInfoB);     
    moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleAModule>();
    moduleCatalog.AddModule<ModuleCModule>();
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/madfisht3/DependentModules) is an example for the wpf.

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work. I still get the same error. I updated my question to include this

Comment: Try to run github code. I used this tip in the enterprise application. It works fine.

Comment: I ran it and it works fine but in my project i still get the MainStepperModule loaded before the Infrastructure one. I wander if it is because MainStepperModule contains the initial view which is used

Comment: I don't recommend you load infrastructure module as a module. Modules shoulds have a hard reference to a infrastructure library. Can you share the code?

Comment: The whole project is a bit heavy and i only have difficulty with service registration. Also, the code is on a private repo. Why having Infrastructure as a library is better than a module ?

Comment: @LuftWaffle because all your projects are related to an infrastructure library. Interfaces are located in this library and for loosely coupled application you must use these interfaces instead of modules class names. Try to exclude all attributes from your application (only in classes that implement IModule interface) and repeat code in your ConfigureModuleCatalog method.

Comment: But where should i implement my service interfaces ? Because i still need to register them as singleton so in Infrastructure or elsewhere the problem is the same.

Comment: @LuftWaffle you must implement service interfaces in your service classes. Register your service class into RegisterTypes method your module. After that, you can call your services through dependency injection (Call your interface in ViewModel constructor).

Comment: Yes i know all of that, i wanted to know where to register them if Infrastructure is not a module any more ? As only a class implementing IModule can register types.

Comment: @LuftWaffle when your module is loading, it runs a method RegisterTypes of your class which implements IModule interface. In RegisterTypes you should register your service class. Your IModule class is in the same library as a service class.

Comment: Sorry, i'm having a hard time to understand. So, Infrastructure should be a library but it should also have a class implementing IModule. So it's juste a module then. Also don't forget that i was already registering my service classes in an IModule implementation. The problement is the order of loading of the differents IModule